# when generate select statement it give me strange text as &gt; when select data?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I work on SQL server 2012 I face issue : there are generated strange text when select from @Body

as "`&gt;`"

How to remove that and why is generated ?

this signature as `&gt;` do problem for me when do select data

select @Body from table

it give me error incorrect syntax near ';'

sample data :

```
create table #FinalTable
(
PART_ID nvarchar(50) ,
CompanyName  nvarchar(50),
PartNumber nvarchar(50),
DKFeatureName nvarchar(100),
value nvarchar(50),
StatusId  int,
DisplayOrder  int,
splitFlag bit
)

insert into #FinalTable(
PART_ID  ,
CompanyName ,
PartNumber ,
DKFeatureName  ,
value   ,
StatusId  ,
DisplayOrder ,
splitFlag)
values
('1222','Honda','silicon','package','15.50Am',2,5,0),
('1900','MERCEIS','GLASS','family','90.00Am',2,2,1),--have column per Unit on @Header because FlagAllow=1
('5000','TOYOTA','alominia','source','70.20kg',2,1,0),
('8000','MACDA','motor','parametric','50.40kg',2,3,1),--have column per Unit on @Header because FlagAllow=1
('8900','JEB','mirror','noparametric','75.35kg',2,4,0)



DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT
    @Body = STUFF(
        (                                                                                                           
        SELECT ', ' +  case when A.splitFlag = 1 and a.value<> '-' and (a.Value is not null)  then 'LEFT(' + QUOTENAME (A.DKFeatureName) + ',PATINDEX(''%[^0-9.]%'',' + QUOTENAME (A.DKFeatureName)  + '+ ' + ''' ''' + ')-1) as ['+A.DKFeatureName+'],(CASE WHEN PATINDEX(''%[^0-9.]%'', '+ A.DKFeatureName + ') > 0 THEN RIGHT('+ QUOTENAME (A.DKFeatureName) +',LEN('+ QUOTENAME (A.DKFeatureName) +') - PATINDEX(''%[^0-9.]%'','+ QUOTENAME (A.DKFeatureName) +')+1)) ELSE NULL END) as  ['+A.DKFeatureName +'Units'+']' else quotename(A.DKFeatureName) end
            FROM #FinalTable A 
            where StatusId=2
                 ORDER BY A.DisplayOrder
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ),1,2,''
    )
   print @Body
```

string generated as below :

```
[Series], [Cable Type], LEFT([Impedance],PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',[Impedance]+ ' ')-1) as [Impedance],(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', Impedance) &gt; 0 THEN RIGHT([Impedance],LEN([Impedance]) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',[Impedance])+1)) ELSE NULL END) as  [ImpedanceUnits], LEFT([Frequency - Max],PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',[Frequency - Max]+ ' ')-1) as [Frequency - Max],(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', Frequency - Max) &gt; 0 THEN RIGHT([Frequency - Max],LEN([Frequency - Max]) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',[Frequency - Max])+1)) ELSE NULL END) as  [Frequency - MaxUnits], [Color]
```

Expected result gt must be > and remove semi colon and &

```
[Series], [Cable Type], LEFT([Impedance],PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',[Impedance]+ ' ')-1) as [Impedance],(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', Impedance) > 0 THEN RIGHT([Impedance],LEN([Impedance]) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',[Impedance])+1)) ELSE NULL END) as  [ImpedanceUnits], LEFT([Frequency - Max],PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',[Frequency - Max]+ ' ')-1) as [Frequency - Max],(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', Frequency - Max) > 0 THEN RIGHT([Frequency - Max],LEN([Frequency - Max]) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',[Frequency - Max])+1)) ELSE NULL END) as  [Frequency - MaxUnits], [Color]
```

I need display gt& as > 0

Comment: Your data is XML, and the character, `>` cannot be represented in XML data. Therefore `&gt;` is used. This is expected behaviour as it created **valid** XML. Something like `<body> 7 > 5</body>` would be invalid XML.

Comment: I need to display it as > because I will make select data from generated text body

Comment: Then provide us with an [mre] along with your expected results.

Comment: We can't run that, we don't have any DDL or data for `#FinalTable`.

Comment: Seems like my stab in the dark works then.

Comment: Then please do consider marking it as the answer, so that future readers know it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `TYPE` key word to enforce the characters to be retained, and then extract the value of your text in the generated XML instead using `value`:

```
DECLARE @Body nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @Body = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CASE
                                         WHEN A.splitFlag = 1
                                          AND A.value <> '-'
                                          AND (A.Value IS NOT NULL) THEN 'LEFT(' + QUOTENAME(A.DKFeatureName) + ',PATINDEX(''%[^0-9.]%'',' + QUOTENAME(A.DKFeatureName) + '+ ' + ''' ''' + ')-1) as [' + A.DKFeatureName + '],(CASE WHEN PATINDEX(''%[^0-9.]%'', ' + A.DKFeatureName + ') > 0 THEN RIGHT(' + QUOTENAME(A.DKFeatureName) + ',LEN(' + QUOTENAME(A.DKFeatureName) + ') - PATINDEX(''%[^0-9.]%'',' + QUOTENAME(A.DKFeatureName) + ')+1)) ELSE NULL END) as  [' + A.DKFeatureName + 'Units' + ']'
                                         ELSE QUOTENAME(A.DKFeatureName)
                                    END
                      FROM #FinalTable A
                      WHERE StatusId = 2
                      ORDER BY A.DisplayOrder
                     FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,'');
PRINT @Body;
```